# What does Adafruit motorshield max amperage mean?

Tags: motor, amperage

On the Adafruit motorshield it says "1.2A per motor (3A max)." What exactly is this telling me, that the motors are drawing 1.2 amps from the battery?

Comment: Certainly 1.2A continuous current and 3A peak current (at startup) max per motor channel.

Comment: @MisterMystère  - that is incorrect. 1.2A is a peak current rating per channel.  The continuous current rating is a mere 600 mA per channel.

Comment: You're right, I only interpreted the sentence without taking the time to check the facts (hence the "certainly" ;) ). Words matter, Adafruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that if you try and use motors that draw more than 1.2A each, or more than a total of 3A between all the motors, the driver chip will explode in a cloud of Magic Smoke™.

Just like this one did:

[image]

Comment: Are you serious? Will it really ruin the board??

Comment: If you try to draw more current through the chip than the chip is designed to handle then yes it can ruin the board.

Comment: I'd replace "will" by "may" - it's up to the OP if he is willing to take the risk of a few percents above the rating, for example :)

Comment: @MisterMystère That decreases the dramatic impact though.

Comment: I'll give you that, the fun must far outweigh the added value of this minor tweak :) In that case I suggest adding a picture of ninjas in the midst of a smoke bomb, or a wizard vanishing in smoke.

Comment: @MisterMystère Or the ubiquitous mushroom cloud...?

Comment: I'm so curious right now.

Comment: https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--k24qq0xq--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_320/1813aqov5wc2jjpg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into the manual and schematics of the board in question, it is unclear whether the board will be damaged or if the board will simply not provide more current than specced -- i.e., more than 1.2Amps/channel or 3.0 Amps total.

My suspicion is that drivers will go over temperature and get damaged, as building protection into the board will raise costs, but without a part number, there really is no way to know.

Comment: Good point. Based on the specs given it is probably the [Adafruit motor shield V2](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1438) which uses a TB6612. This chip is thermally protected so (in theory) it shouldn't blow up.